# Calculate extra column in group by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

In sure this should be simple, but I'm having a [brain fart](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Brain+Fart) over it.

In SQL Server 2005, how do you add an "extra count" to a [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) query?

Consider the following...

```
;WITH DATA AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS TYPEID, 0 AS ACTIONNEEDED 
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS TYPEID, 0 AS ACTIONNEEDED 
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 2 AS TYPEID, 0 AS ACTIONNEEDED 
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 2 AS TYPEID, 1 AS ACTIONNEEDED 
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS ID, 2 AS TYPEID, 0 AS ACTIONNEEDED 
)
SELECT TYPEID, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM DATA
GROUP BY TYPEID
```

The result is...

```
TYPEID  TOTAL
1       2
2       3
```

But what I need is an extra column that totals the number of rows where `ACTIONNEEDED=1`...

```
TYPEID  TOTAL ACTIONNEEDED
1       2     0
2       3     1
```

Note: unfortunately due to project constraints, I'm restricted to SQL Server 2005 compatible answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM` with an inner `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT 
    TYPEID, 
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionNeeded = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ACTIONNEEDED
FROM DATA
GROUP BY TYPEID
```

Comment: Doh, it's so simple!!  Thank you. (Will accept when allowed)

Comment: In fact, it's even simpler... just `SUM(ACTIONNEEDED)` is enough for my needs